# Requesting a permission in Android | Cannot resolve symbol MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS

Tags: android, permissions

I am trying to access the user's files, and I have tried it this way:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Permission is not granted
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        }
    } else {
        // Permission has already been granted
    }
```

Just like [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java)

Now Android Studio tells me: Cannot resolve symbol MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS

Why is this?

I'm sorry if this question has been asked before, but I have looked and I couldn't find an answer to my problem.

Thanks in advance

Max

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as it's mentioned

```
    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
    // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
    // result of the request.
```

so declare it, better to create a separate class as

```
class Constants{
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 100;
}
```

and use it as

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                    Constants.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
```

Comment: did you mind provide/point to the resource where we could find the correct value for each permission?

Comment: @AdiPrasetyo the constant value can be anything(like roll number in one class(Activity)) but should be unique so that you can implement flow of control accordingly though you actual permission constants [see Manifest class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission)

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare that variable before using it.
Try adding this line

```
 public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 100;// . or any other value
```

Answer (score 0):

This message below is in the link sent by you

> MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the result of the request.

MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an int variable, you can use it to get the result your request. If you dont want the result, just put 0 (or another int > 0)

Answer (score 0):

MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an app defined constant . Hence you should create public static int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 45; I am taking 45 as an example but can be any constant.